# PHP isset doesnt work on html button

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="service.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="button" name="getMa" onclick="window.open('service.php')"value="MA anzeigen"/>
                <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" name="MA_ID" value=""/><br><br>
            </fieldset>
```

service.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['getMa']))
    {
        echo "getMa gedrückt";
    }
```

I just want to know which of my buttons has been pushed, what am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated, I'm new to this stuff, thx guys
Regards
Ismir

Comment: Show more of your form.html + service.php

Comment: which method are you set in form GET or POST?

Comment: At least button should have a `value` also

Comment: Try to scan by print "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); print "</pre>";

Comment: more code added, I'm using POST-Method

Comment: If it's not a typo - add a space before `value=""`

Comment: Why do you have a window.open('service.php') in your onClick?

Comment: Why you are using `onclick="window.open('service.php')"` just remove it and it will work

Comment: If you want to open `service.php` in a new window use `target='_blank'` in `<form>` tag instead of using `onclick="window.open('service.php')"` and try changing `type="button"` to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove   `onclick="window.open('service.php')"`, the `action` attribute will submit the form. You are basically opening a window directly so it will not be having any information about the `POST` parameters

and yes change

```
 type="button"
```

to

```
 type="submit"
```

Comment: I removed onclick, but then nothing happens, means service.php will not be opened, regard I have three buttons in this form

Comment: type="button" to type="submit"

Comment: This worked for me, thk u very much, I check this hook as soon as I'm able to ;)